# Get the index of an element inbetween two other elements

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to get the index of an element without a parent. The child elements are usually between other "master" elements that are considered as a parent but the child elements are not in a container and I want to get the index starting from the "master" element.

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/t0Lagqnd/

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr data-number="0">
            <td>This is a master row 0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-parent="0" data-number="01"> <!-- 1 -->
            <td>This is a child row 01</td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-parent="0" data-number="02"> <!-- 2 -->
            <td>This is a child row 02</td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-parent="0" data-number="03"> <!-- 3 -->
            <td>This is a child row 03</td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-number="1">
            <td>This is a master row 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-parent="1" data-number="11"> <!-- 1 -->
            <td>This is a child row 11</td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-parent="1" data-number="12"> <!-- 2 -->
            <td>This is a child row 12</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Lets say I targeted the row with a number of 03 (I'm using id's so I can't use numbers) and I want to get its index.

Comment: See: http://api.jquery.com/prev/

Comment: *"I'm using id's so I can't use numbers"* I think you meant "I'm using numbers so I can't use `id`s". If so: Yes you can, but it's a pain to select them with CSS selectors. (Possible, but a pain.)

Comment: What I meant was that data-number attributes have a database id value so the data-number values can be random so that means I can't use stuff like nth-of-type nth-child etc.. I need to select the element by it's database id. I'm really out of my explaining zone today sorry..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean the index of the `tr` relative to the "master" `tr` it follows?

If so, I thik you're looking for `prevUntil`, which collects preceding siblings *until* something that matches a selector; in your case, the selector to match would be `tr:not([data-parent])` as the master rows don't have `data-parent` attributes:

```
var num = "03";
var index = $("tr[data-number=" + num + "]").prevUntil("tr:not([data-parent])").length;
```

```js
$("table").on("click", "tr[data-number]", function() {
  alert($(this).prevUntil("tr:not([data-parent])").length);
});
```

```html
<p>Click a child row in the below to see its index:</p>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr data-number="0">
            <td>This is a master row 0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-parent="0" data-number="01">
            <td>This is a child row 01</td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-parent="0" data-number="02">
            <td>This is a child row 02</td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-parent="0" data-number="03">
            <td>This is a child row 03</td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-number="1">
            <td>This is a master row 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-parent="1" data-number="11">
            <td>This is a child row 11</td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-parent="1" data-number="12">
            <td>This is a child row 12</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Another option is to change the markup so that "master" rows are in their own `tbody` and then all of the "child" rows related to the previous master are in their own `tbody`. Then you could just use `index`:

```js
$("table").on("click", "tr[data-parent]", function() {
  alert($(this).index());
});
```

```html
<p>Click a child row below to see its index:</p>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr data-number="0">
            <td>This is a master row 0</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr data-parent="0" data-number="01"> <!-- 1 -->
            <td>This is a child row 01</td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-parent="0" data-number="02"> <!-- 2 -->
            <td>This is a child row 02</td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-parent="0" data-number="03"> <!-- 3 -->
            <td>This is a child row 03</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr data-number="1">
            <td>This is a master row 1</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr data-parent="1" data-number="11"> <!-- 1 -->
            <td>This is a child row 11</td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-parent="1" data-number="12"> <!-- 2 -->
            <td>This is a child row 12</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Didn't think of this way previously. Thanks! :)

Comment: I sadly can't use multiple tbody elements like that because of the way I'm laying out my rows using foreach at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('tr[data-number=03]' ).index()
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/t0Lagqnd/2/)**

Comment: No, that counts relative to **all** siblings in the container. The OP made quite a point about calling out that it wasn't just the index within the container (although it could have been even clearer).

Comment: This method I already tried. As I stated the [data-parent] elements are as children and the [data-number] without the parent data attribute is like a container or a "master" but I cannot use tbody as a container because of the way I'm foreaching the rows. I want to start counting the index from it's "master" row. I apologize for not making the question as clear as it could've been.

Answer (score -2):

Do you mean this http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

or this http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-prefix-selector/

```
$( "table tr:nth-child(4)" )

$( "tr[data-number|='03']" )
```